# Find average of elements in an Array based on Date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using mongodb and I would like to find average age of students who have joined after **13th Feb 2014**. I tried aggregation framework but didn't manage to get to the solution.

Example of my documents:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "zipcode" : 63109,
    "students" : [ 
        {
            doj: ISODate("2014-02-12T00:00:00Z"),
            "name" : "john",
            "school" : 102,
            "age" : 10
        }, 
        {
            doj: ISODate("2014-02-14T00:00:00Z"),
            "name" : "jess",
            "school" : 102,
            "age" : 11
        }, 
        {
            doj: ISODate("2014-02-13T00:00:00Z")
            "name" : "jeff",
            "school" : 108,
            "age" : 15
        }
    ]
},    
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "zipcode" : 63109,
    "students" : [ 
        {
            doj: ISODate("2014-02-14T00:00:00Z"),
            "name" : "john",
            "school" : 102,
            "age" : 16
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me find the solution. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the collection name is student you can use the following aggregate query:

```
db.students.aggregate(
{$unwind:'$students'}, //unwinds student array
{$match:{'students.doj':{$gt:ISODate("2014-02-13T00:00:00Z")}}}, //gets entries of student whose date of join greater than 13th February 2014
{$group:{_id:null,average_age:{$avg:'$students.age'}}} //gets the average
)
```

In the above query if you want to group your data based on zipcode, then you can replace the group statement with the following statement

```
{$group:{_id:'$zipcode',average_age:{$avg:'$students.age'}}}
```